# Method Illuminate\Http\Request::isDirty does not exist. Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, model, controller, voyager

I'm using voyager admin panel. I want to check the attributes that are changed when I submit the form. I'm using **isDirty()** & **getDirty()** but that is not working.
It is showing that the error

> Method Illuminate\Http\Request::isDirty does not exist.

Sometimes showing this error.

> Call to a member function isDirty() on string

update Controller

```php
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $slug = $this->getSlug($request);

    $dataType = Voyager::model('DataType')->where('slug', '=', $slug)->first();

    // Compatibility with Model binding.
    $id = $id instanceof \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
        ? $id->{$id->getKeyName()}
        : $id;

    $model = app($dataType->model_name);
    $query = $model->query();
   
    $data = $query->findOrFail($id);

    $this->insertUpdateData($request, $slug, $dataType->editRows, $data);

    // That part is showing an error
    dd($request->isDirty(['status']));

    return $redirect->with([
        'message'    => __('voyager::generic.successfully_updated')." {$dataType->getTranslatedAttribute('display_name_singular')}",
        'alert-type' => 'success',
    ]);
}
```

Comment: A model is dirty, aka changed. A request is not.

Comment: What should I use when attribute is changed?

Comment: you would have to call that method on the model instance that you changed an attribute for

Comment: `$data->isDirty('status')` should work **before** the data is saved.

Comment: Can anyone please write the code so I can easily understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Request will not show the results it will work only with the model. So I used **$data** instead of **$request**. And I've to show it in an array. Something like this.

```
$data = $query->findOrFail($id);
$data->status  = $request->status;
dd($data->isDirty('status'));
```

I works on my side.